# Selenium Can Not Find Script Tags?

Tags: python, selenium

I have `<script language = 'javascript'></script>` in `html` file.
I used  `driver.find_elements_by_xpath("//script[@language]")` but it's not working.
How can i fix it?

Answer (score 0):

See if this works:

```
driver.find_element_by_tag_name("script")
```

Answer (score 0):

I would try this:

```
driver.find_element_by_xpath("//script[@language='javascript']")
```

Comment: Thanks.It's in a loop with some other xpaths in this driver.find_elements_by_xpath("//name[@attribute]") pattern.I think just script not working between them

Comment: If so we need to know several parent elements to find unique sequence locator

Answer (score 0):

You are using `find_elements` which will return a list. for a single web element we want to use `find_element`.

if there's a single `language` attribute, you can probably try this  :

```
script_web_element = driver.find_element_by_xpath("//script[@language]")
```